# How can a priest's father be something else than a priest?

Tags: leviticus

How can Zabud be a priest, with his father Nathan being a prophet?  Weren't the Levites singled off to serve as priests for the LORD?

> Azariah the son of Nathan was over the officers; Zabud the son of Nathan was priest and king’s friend;
> (1Kings 4:15 ESV)

Answer (score 2):

How can Zabud be a priest, with his father Nathan being a prophet?

Ellicott explains that this is not Nathan the prophet:

> (5) Son of Nathan.--Probably Nathan, son of David, and own brother of Solomon (1Chronicles 3:5), is here intended; for the title Cohen, here given to Zabud, is expressly ascribed in 2Samuel 8:18 to the "sons of David;" and **Nathan the prophet always has his title, "the prophet," appended to his name** wherever first mentioned in this book. (See 1Kings 1:8; 1Kings 1:10; 1Kings 1:22; 1Kings 1:32, &c.) . . .

Pulpit comments similarly:

> Keil and Bahr pronounce somewhat positively that this Nathan is **not** the prophet of that name, but Nathan the son of David (2 Samuel 5:14; Luke 3:31).

Comment: *the title Cohen [...] is expressly ascribed in 2 Samuel 8:18 to the sons of David* - Which only **begs the question** why that was so; nevertheless, a good start.

Answer (score 0):

**Read [1 Kings 4] - from the beginning, specifically verses 1-5 regarding the wise but idolatrous King Solomon and his Priestly Ministers (Princes)** of Israel after the death of King David.

- In verse 1, we learn Shlomoh שְׁלֹמֹ֔ה was Melek ("King") of יִשְׂרָאֵֽל Yisrael :

"And King Solomon was king over all Israel." (וַֽיְהִי֙ הַמֶּ֣לֶךְ שְׁלֹמֹ֔ה מֶ֖לֶךְ עַל־כָּל־יִשְׂרָאֵֽל)

- In verse 2, we learn עֲזַרְיָהוּ Azariahu (who was son of צָד֖וֹק הַכֹּהֵֽן Tsadoq The-Priest) was considered a Sar שָׂר "Minister" (Prince) of Yisrael serving King Shlomoh.

"And these [were] the Ministers whom he had : Azariahu the son of Zadok The-Priest." (וְאֵ֥לֶּה הַשָּׂרִ֖ים אֲשֶׁר־ל֑וֹ עֲזַרְיָ֥הוּ בֶן־צָד֖וֹק הַכֹּהֵֽן)

- In verse 3, we learn about two Scribes : אֱלִיחֹ֧רֶף Elihoreph וַאֲחִיָּ֛ה and-Ahiah, and one Recorder : יְהוֹשָׁפָ֥ט Yehoshafat (who served as data entry for King Shlomoh documenting his decrees).

"Elihoreph and Ahiah, the sons of Shisha, scribes, Jehoshaphat the son of Ahilud the recorder." (אֱלִיחֹ֧רֶף וַאֲחִיָּ֛ה בְּנֵ֥י שִׁישָׁ֖א סֹפְרִ֑ים יְהוֹשָׁפָ֥ט בֶּן־אֲחִיל֖וּד הַמַּזְכִּֽיר)

In verse 4, we learn צָד֖וֹק הַכֹּהֵֽן Zadok the-Priest is still alive & guides all of Israel's Priests (including his son Azariahu) in their service to YHVH while ministering to King Shlomoh.

"And Benaiahu the son of Jehoiada [was] over the host, and Zadok and Abiathar [were] the priests." (וּבְנָיָ֥הוּ בֶן־יְהוֹיָדָ֖ע עַל־הַצָּבָ֑א וְצָד֥וֹק וְאֶבְיָתָ֖ר כֹּהֲנִֽים)

Finally in verse 5, we learn Nathan the Priest (not the prophet) & Nathan's son Zavud were friends to King Shlomoh.

"And Azariahu the son of Nathan [was] over the officers, and Zavud [the] son of Nathan [the] Priest - friend [of] The-King." (וַעֲזַרְיָ֥הוּ בֶן־נָתָ֖ן עַל־הַנִּצָּבִ֑ים וְזָב֧וּד בֶּן־נָתָ֛ן כֹּהֵ֖ן רֵעֶ֥ה הַמֶּֽלֶךְ)